# PHP Ajax Load only new content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

I am working on a simple Chat right now, its already working, but its not very efficient.
Whenever I run my script it refreshes the whole Chat and loads the content over and over again.

**Im trying to find a way that the script only loads new content from my chat database, the old messages shouldnt load over and over again.**

This is the part from my index.php:

```
<div id="chat" class="full rund">

<table border="1" class="full chattable">
            <?php
            $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM chat";
            $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)) {?>
                <tr class="chattr">
                    <td style="width:200px;"><h3 class="text">&#428;&#968;&#428; &#9762; <?php echo $row->name;?>:</h3></td>
                    <td style="width:440px;"><p><h3 class="text"><?php echo $row->text;?></h3></p></td>
                    <td style="width:160px;"><h3 class="text"><?php echo $row->timestamp;?></h3></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is my chat.js:

```
setInterval( "updateShouts()", 1000 );

function fx(form,target){
var _target=target;
var url=form.action;  
var data=$(form)[(form.method.match(/^post$/i))?'serializeArray':'serialize']();
$(_target).load(url,data,function(){setTimeout(function(){
$(_target).empty();
},0);});
return false;}
```

`function updateShouts(){
    $('#chat').load('php/latestMsg.php');
    }`

My latestMsg.php (same as index):

```
<div id="chat" class="full rund">

    <table border="1" class="full chattable">
                <?php
                $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM chat";
                $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)) {?>
                    <tr class="chattr">
                        <td style="width:200px;"><h3 class="text">&#428;&#968;&#428; &#9762; <?php echo $row->name;?>:</h3></td>
                        <td style="width:440px;"><p><h3 class="text"><?php echo $row->text;?></h3></p></td>
                        <td style="width:160px;"><h3 class="text"><?php echo $row->timestamp;?></h3></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I hope anyone can help me, ive been searching for a long time now and I couldnt find anything that solves my problem!
Thanks :)

Comment: I would probably keep track in the session on the server what messages have already been sent to the user. With a timestamp or the ID of the last sent message.

Comment: what he might want to look into is web-sockets... then you don't have to update the page at all.

Answer (score 1):

2 Solutions.

1. You will need a way to mark your messages as read, per user of course.
2. You can ignore that and only read back the last X messages.

Comment: Last x messages could be temporal... i.e. last x minutes.  OP might find RFC,s on SIP, XMPP, IRC, etc to be good reads.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your chat table, you must add 'unread' field or something, to identify  the message status (read/unread) , same like @geggleto solution
2. add filter to your query to something like this :

   $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE timestamp between '$from' AND '$to' ";

to make sure you have a role to limit message by time

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)
But if I would just add a filter, my old messages would disappear, since the whole div refreshs every second and replaces the div content with the new messages.
How do I manage it that the new messages will appear below my old messages without deleting my old messages?